# A function with two limit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

When I was doing the following problem：

> Investigate the continuity of the following functions
> $y = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}(x>0)$

I know that this function can be written as a piecewise function:$when\  x > 1, y = 0, \ when 0 < x < 1, y = 1$

I want to find the left limit of the function at $x = 1$, obviously, it is $1$.But if I don't write the function as a piecewise function, and I solve for it directly, it's going to look like this with two limit symbols:

> $y = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}(x>0)$

How to understand the limits of this form，can we solve this limit directly?

Comment: In short... you cannot write it as two limits and hope the value is the same.
In long.. let $f(x) := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^n}$. Now your goal is to find the value of $f(1)$. And your final expression hopes to find $f(1)$ by computing $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x)$. But note that $f(1)$ equals $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x)$ iff $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$, and here it is NOT.

Comment: There is a priori nothing wrong with the notation $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$; but since you have already rewritten $y$ using much simpler expressions with the piecewise form, there is no benefit to using $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$.

Comment: Worth noting that mathematicians love investigating whether permuting symbols like $\lim$, $\sum$ and $\int$ is allowed or not; that is, there are lots of theorems of the form "If $g$ has some particular properties, then $\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x, n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 0} g(x, n)$" or variations with $\sum_x \sum_y = \sum_y \sum_x$, $\int \int dx dy = \int \int dy dx$, $\lim \int = \int \lim$, etc. Those equalities are **not** true in general, but there has been a lot of research to identify situations where they are true.

Comment: Adding parentheses also could perhaps help remove some of your confusion: $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left( \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n} \right)$$

Comment: @Stef I got it, thank you for your patient explanation!